# PHP rotate video

Tags: php, iphone, video, youtube, rotation

I have my own video sharing app,

My question is... is there any library,script or something else, to help me in rotating videos whatever their file extension is?

Many peoples are uploading videos but sometimes i found video (guessing shared with iphones or mobile phones) and i see them horizontally instead of vertically...

Does anyone have any ideas how to rotate them dynamically?

Comment: However, libraries, such as `GD` offer media manipulation abilities, and that is what OP is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with any "libraries" that will do that. I think your better bet would be to find a command-prompt-enabled video software package (like [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/support/faqs/av-faqs.php) [See Q7]) that PHP can execute via command prompt on the fly.

Comment: ok man thanks but i would like that php do that automatically if possible... :)

Comment: Understood. Keep in mind, you will get better, faster results from a software bundle designed to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't do that, and there are no extensions that I know off, made for that purpose.

You can use ffmpeg to manipulate videos, by calling it from your scripts (see shell_execute() and such functions). Reading [the ffmpeg documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) will help you figure what can (and can't) be done with that powerful tool.